# Match specific user's traffic both in OUTPUT and in INPUT to use quota on it

Tags: iptables, firewall

How can I convert:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota --quota 10240000 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

for use in INPUT?

I tried it like this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -A INPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota --quota 10240000 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

but I didn't succeed.

Comment: so there's no way to convert to INPUT?

Comment: could you help me with this solution? I will be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

The man page tells:

> [`owner`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#owner)
>
> This module attempts to match various  characteristics  of  the
> packet creator, for locally generated packets. **This match is only
> valid in the OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains**. Forwarded packets do
> not have any socket associated with them. Packets from kernel
> threads do have a socket, but usually no owner.

So there's no direct equivalent for INPUT. The reason is simple: an incoming packet doesn't come from a process, so it's not possible to check the socket owner of the process that will (very soon but has not yet) receive(d) this packet (despite the existence of a [`socket` match](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#socket) which can do such advance lookup but doesn't have any owner-related feature).

### [`connmark`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#CONNMARK)

What can be done instead, is to [associate a conntrack mark](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#CONNMARK) to the (first) time an outgoing packet of this flow is associated with an user, and mark subsequent packets, including incoming packets, from the conntrack mark. It's then possible to use other features like quota.

1. Blindly restores a mark from the conntrack flow to the packet: the mark if any (0 means there was none) is now available on the *incoming* packet.

   This could have been done in mangle/INPUT instead, since the overall feature makes sense only to local traffic (so not to traffic passing through FORWARD chains), but this is easier to not care about rule ordering later and do it in mangle/PREROUTING (one can choose to optimize and move it to mangle/INPUT).

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
   ```

   (add more related rules here or in mangle/INPUT or filter/INPUT as needed that should start with `-m mark --mark 1`).
2. Also restore the mark from the conntrack flow to the outgoing packet. Then if there's no mark, do the owner test to add a firewall mark to the packet

   Chronologically that's the place where the mark will be initially set, since testing the owner of a packet can be done only in the output path.

   The mark test before setting the mark is there to possibly allow with later rules to change again this mark (and ultimately the conntrack mark) without then getting it overwritten again on next output packet.

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
   iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 0 -m owner --uid-owner root -j MARK --set-mark 1
   ```

   (add more related rules here or in filter/OUTPUT as needed that should start with `-m mark --mark 1`).
3. Save back the firewall mark on the packet to the conntrack flow mark (it will also save a mark that was changed)

   This is done in POSTROUTING so there's no rule ordering to care about (it could also have been done in mangle/OUTPUT).

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
   ```

Depending on the problem some optimization is probably possible, but this gives the idea.

With this setup, as soon as a packet in a flow gets for the first time a mark (either the first packet of an originally outgoing flow from a root process, or the first reply packet of an originally incoming flow to a root process), the flow will inherit the mark and any further packets of this flow will also inherit this mark, both ways.

Caveat: this method won't allow to account the the first packet in an *incoming* flow. For quota accounting that means the first payload size won't be accounted (eg: received UDP query, or of the first TCP incoming (SYN) packet (not that important, unless it's a TCP Fast Open with initial payload)).

---

### Addressing OP's specific question

Once above framework is in place one can now check the mark in INPUT or OUTPUT to know it's about a packet to or from the root user.

1. INPUT

   The [`quota2` match](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#quota2) in (default) count down mode returns true as long as there is quota remaining: the test must be inverted with a `!`, as documented:

   > When  counting  down from the initial quota, **the counter will stop at 0
   > and the match will return false** [...]

   > [`!`] `--quota` iq
   >
   > Specify  the  initial quota for this counter. If the counter al‐ ready
   > exists, it is not reset. **An "!" may be used to invert the result  of
   > the match**. The negation has no effect when --grow is used.

   to return false and not execute the target DROP until there is no quota left anymore (reaches 0). An other way (not done here) would be to invert the logic of the actions (`-j ACCEPT` followed by a single `-j DROP` rule).

   For OP's [`quota2` match](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#quota2) to then apply in INPUT:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota ! --quota 10000000 -j DROP
   ```

   Note that it didn't make sense to reapply the same mark as in OP's example: this was already done with the previous command in mangle/PREROUTING (just as it was already done with OP's initial command `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -j MARK --set-mark 1`, thus for no additional effect). Instead of `-j DROP` one could jump to a new user chain that will handle basic traffic policing with [rate limit](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#limit). I think applying quota to *root* wouldn't be a good idea, but could make sense for an other user. Anyway that's what OP asked.
2. revised OUTPUT

   Revised OP's *quota2* to apply in OUTPUT like was done in INPUT.

   ```
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota ! --quota 10000000 -j DROP
   ```

   As before one could instead choose rate limit once the global quota has been consumed.

Comment: how can i add this new rule to be accept with

**iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner root -m quota2 --name 10mbps --quota 10000000 -j MARK --set-mark 1**

Comment: worked as expected yes more when the quota reaches its 10mb spent the traffic still continue, I would like this connection to be stopped immediately when it reaches its given quota both input and output .

Comment: @AB yes I read every part of what you wrote and thank you very much for the help but still did not understand this part to reject when the quota zeroes with -j DROP

What I tried was

iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota --quota 10000000 -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -m mark --mark 1 -m quota2 --name 10mb_quota --quota 10000000 -j DROP

plus the traffic is frozen when added -j DROP before ending the quota I'm confused I apologize for not understanding much I'm a bit of a beginner in the world of iptables.

Comment: I changed the rules to do what you wanted (mind the `!`).

Comment: @AB sensational!!!! I was surprised by the result and it worked as expected now stopping user traffic!!Thank you very much!!!