# iptables block IP range user

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm trying to block an IP range using

> iptables -A INPUT -s 185.0.0.0/8 -j DROP

This rule works perfectly but will affect all users on the network.

I want to make this happen for individual users so as not to affect everyone in general.

would like to make this block happen for a specific user using

> owner --uid-owne < username >

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because our language is English. Please translate it or try asking in language-specific community.

Comment: sorry I understand the english language was a typo on my part, again a thousand apologies and thanks for the warning!

Comment: See also my answer in this Q/A (where I had to change the title so it means something): https://serverfault.com/questions/1138626/match-specific-users-traffic-both-in-output-and-in-input-to-use-quota-on-it , where I explain how to track the *flow* where an *output packet* 's owner was present, both ways rather than output-only. OP doesn't capitalize on it. Of course for this new problem this might not be applicable (one has to accept a packet first, to get a reply with an owner)

Answer (score 1):

The **owner** module of Iptables can be used to filter packets based on the user who generated them. However, this only works for outgoing packets (OUTPUT). Therefore, you can't use **owner** to filter incoming packets (INPUT).

So if you want to block all outgoing packets from a specific user to a certain network, you can use a rule like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner username -d 185.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Replace username with the username for which you want to apply the rule. This rule will block all outgoing traffic from that user to the 185.0.0.0/8 network.

If you want to apply this rule for a specific process, you can use the **--pid-owner** option:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --pid-owner pid -d 185.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Here, replace **pid** with the process ID for which you want to apply the rule.

Please note that these rules will not block incoming traffic from the user or process, and they will also not block outgoing traffic to other networks. You need to modify these or add additional rules to meet these needs.

Comment: how can i make blocks for INPUT too?  is there a simple way to do a level lock of that level for INPUT?  and thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!!

Comment: It is impossible to block by owner match in INPUT, because on that stage the system doesn't know is there really a listening socket on that port and who's owner of that socket. But it is enough to block in OUTPUT to achieve your goal. Users will not be able to initiate connections, and reply to incoming connections, so essentially no communication will be possible in that case.

Comment: yes yes with output worked as expected, thank you very much!